# Cambiar nombre de la URL en firebase hosting

Tags: html, firebase, url

Tengo una web simple (solo html y css) alojada en firebase hosting, y tengo todas las paginas html dentro de una carpeta, ¿Cómo puedo eliminar el nombre de la carpeta de la ruta?

por ejemplo cambiar la url de

**ejemplo.com/carpeta/pagina1** a
**ejemplo.com/pagina1**

Por lo que he visto no puedo usar archivo htaccess en firebase hosting y en firebase.json probé muchas cosas pero nada funcionó. Tengo muchas URL y busco la forma de quitar el nombre de la carpeta de todas las url, sin tener que eliminar la carpeta en si.
Alguien sabe como se puede hacer? Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Como dijiste Firebase no tiene archivo htaccess pero lo reemplaza el firebase.json. Puedes hacer este "cambio de url" con los `rewrites`, donde puedes configurar que rutas vayan al mismo archivo. Algo asi:

```
"hosting": {
  // ...
  "rewrites": [ {
    "source": "/pagina1",
    "destination": "/carpeta/pagina1"
  } ]
}
```

Comment: Gracias! Eso funciona, pero hay que hacer eso con cada url de mi web? o existe alguna forma para aplicarlo a todas las url? @Josephdavid07